# Idiom for "dominate"

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for an idiom that means "dominate" and can be used in the following sentence:

> Our team ***dominated*** from the beginning to the end.

Comment: Your sentence is already idiomatic in the context of sporting games.

Comment: @Lawrence Does the verb 'rule' work there?

Comment: Yes, *ruled* could replace *dominated* in that sentence, but I think *dominated* conveys the idea more effectively. Is there any reason you prefer a different word?

Comment: You are looking for an expression to replace the word "dominated" in your sentence? *Our team **beat the dead horse** from the beginning to the end.*

Comment: There ain't no term more domineering than "dominate".

Comment: There are many, many idioms for one sports team defeating another. (Try being a sports writer, reporting this very event thousands of times.) Can you be more explicit about what you're trying to describe? Was your team in the lead throughout the game? Did your team win every point? Was it easy?

Comment: Internet lingo "pwned" or "owned" could be used - although rarely outside the internet. But I guess if on the internet, you'd know those already :D

Answer (score 11):

In the context of contests, sporting or otherwise, this idiom springs to mind:

*"Our team **wiped the floor with them** from beginning to end."*

> - **[wipe the floor with:](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wipe-the-floor-with-sb)** to ​defeat someone very ​easily:
>
>   *"I ​hear Italy ​beat France in the ​semifinals last ​night." "Beat them? They ​wiped the ​floor with them!"*

<sub>Cambridge Dictionary</sub>

---

You could also say:

"*we **had them in the palm of our hand** from beginning to end*"

> - [**have in the palm of your hand:**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-sb-in-the-palm-of-your-hand) to have ​complete ​control over someone and to be ​able to make them do anything you ​want:
>
>   *He had the ​audience in the palm of his ​hand.*

<sub>Cambridge Dictionary</sub>

---

Lastly, in Britain, there's an idiom which is commonly used in the circumstances of a contest:

*"Our team **thrashed** them"*

> - **[thrash:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/thrash)** defeat heavily in a contest or match:
>
>   *I thrashed Pete at cards*

<sub>OED</sub>

Answer (score 10):

Agree with **@Lawrence**. Your sentence is idiomatic as it is.

However, if your team exhibited ruthless demonstration of sporting skill and acumen, then you can safely say that you "***[steamrollered](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/steamroller)***" all your opponents.

> an overpowering force, especially one that crushes all opposition with ruthless disregard

[Dictionary.com]

**An [example](http://www.thehindu.com/2000/02/05/stories/07050281.htm)**:

> Australia ***steamrollers*** Pakistan in second final

Comment: I've always said "steamrolls" and "steamrolled" instead of "steamrollers" and "steamrollered". Google ngrams shows the shorter version becoming more popular in the last 20 years or so.

Comment: I've only just noticed, I think you need the verb *steamroll* and not the noun form. Someone gets *steamrolled* see OD examples http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/steamroll

Comment: @Mari-LouA - In InE, **steamrollered** is the frequently used term. The OED page cited by you says "steamrolled" is chiefly a North American usage.

Comment: @Matt using Ngram for this is tricker because *steamroll/er* is both a noun and a verb. Today I learned: steamroller is also a verb

Comment: @Mari-Lou, I checked "steamrolled" vs. "steamrollered" to avoid the noun/verb problem. "Steamrollers" is much more popular than "steamrolls", but as you suggest, that's probably because steamrollers does double duty as both a noun and a verb, while steamrolls is only a verb.

Comment: Additionally, the action that a _steamroller_ does could replace **dominate** in the original example: Our team **crushed/flattened/rolled over** the opposition.

Comment: I don't believe dominate to be idiomatic.  Since the game or the opposing team is not specified, they could have literally been "exercising control over" (the game) from start to finish.  There is no figurative meaning necessary for dominate to make the sentence make sense.  Steamroll, however, does work nicely.

Answer (score 8):

> Our team ***crushed*** the opponents (from start to finish).

An example from the net

> Second match against VSS Kosice became a very different story, they lost 3–0 away and **then crushed the opponents with 6–0 at home**, after a hat-trick by Roger Carlsson.
>   <sub>Wikipedia: [IF Elfsborg in European football](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IF_Elfsborg_in_European_football)</sub>

Answer (score 6):

You can use, "***[have/get the upper hand](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+the+upper+hand)"***:

> - to have power and control over someone or a situation.
>
>   - *By half time, the Italian soccer team seemed to have the upper hand.*

(Cambridge Dictionary of American  idioms)

Answer (score 5):

Not a perfect fit but consider these:

**Lord it over (someone)** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lord+it+over)

> To dominate someone; to direct and control someone.
>
> *"Mr. Smith seems to lord it over his wife."*
>   *"The boss lords it over everyone in the office."*

**Get a leg up on (someone)** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+a+leg+up+on+one)

> To achieve or be in a position of advantage over someone else.
>
> *"One must always be looking for ways to get a leg up on the competition if one wants to succeed in business."*
>   *"I've been practising all summer long, and now I've finally gotten a leg up on Keith in tennis."*

Comment: This has a slightly different meaning, implying a pattern of arrogant behaviour, e.g. [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/lord-it-over-someone): "bully, menace... act big" and [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lord-it-over-someone): "to ​behave as if you are more ​important than someone and have a ​right to ​tell that ​person what to do". A gracious, sportsmanlike team can wipe the floor with the opposition without lording over them; an arrogant high-status team could lord it over their opposition without actually even winning.

Answer (score 5):

I think "owned" would work for you idiomatically.

> Our team *owned them* from the beginning to the end.

Alternately if you are typing on the internet, you would use the below.

> Our team *pwnd.*

Answer (score 4):

You could say, *Our team **had the edge** from the beginning to the end*.

> *the advantage of someone* and *the advantage over someone*
>   ; *an advantage over someone*; *the advantage over someone*; *the edge on someone*; *the edge over someone* a position superior to that of someone else; a status wherein one controls or has superiority or authority over someone else. (Typically: *get ~*; *give someone ~*; *have ~*.) *She'd gotten an advantage over me at the start of the competition*. *I got an edge on Sally, too, and she came in second*. [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+edge+over+someone)

Answer (score 4):

You can use "in the driving seat"....

E.g: our team was in the driving seat from the beginning to the end..

Answer (score 3):

You could use **Outclassed**

The dictionary on [Reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/outclassed) lists it as:

> verb (used with object)
>
> 1. to surpass in excellence or quality, especially by a wide margin; be superior:
>
> "*He far outclasses the other runners in the race.*"

Answer (score 2):

[Whitewash](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/whitewash):

> Sports Informal. a defeat in which the loser fails to score.

Not necessarily the same but if the score was X-0, you could say, 'Our team won the match 5-0, it was a total whitewash.'

[Dictionary.com]

Comment: Hi, The Cat, I really like your answer. Can you include a dictionary link or reference that can support your answer? We don't encourage an answer without it in this community. Please let me know after you edit your answer. I will upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: Okay! I've added a link.

Comment: Great. I copied and pasted essential part of the link, placed a period after *whitewash* and wrote the name of the source. Please try to follow this format. Good luck. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have one of the best words for your sentence, but you could also use:

**Wrecked**

> destroy or severely damage (a structure or vehicle).

"the blast wrecked more than 100 houses"

Answer (score 1):

There is an American English idiom, but one which British speakers are familiar with, it emphasizes the ease of a team's victory

> Our team won the match easily, it was **[like taking candy from a baby](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-like-taking-candy-from-a-baby)**
>   Beating them was the ​easiest thing in the ​world - it was **like taking ​candy from a ​baby**

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the word **overwhelm**, or **rout**.

Meaning:

> defeat completely.
>
> ""his teams overwhelmed their opponents"
>
> Synonyms: defeat (utterly/heavily)

Answer (score 1):

You could say: "Our team **had its own way** from the beginning to the end."

> *[McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/one%27s+way)*. S.v. "one's way." :
>
> ***one's (own) way (with someone or something)**
>
> [get/have] one's control over someone or something. (*Typically: **get ~**; **have ~**.)

Comment: This comes with a warning that it's also a slightly old-fashioned [euphamism for sex...](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/have-one-s-way-with#source-ahdi2) it's seldom used in modern speech, but is often used in period dramas etc (also as ["to have one's wicked way with"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+wicked+way+with)), so it could lead to an unfortunate misunderstanding...

Answer (score 1):

Another one often used in sports:

### [Our team] ran rings around [their team]

Or, "ran circles around".

[Example of real-life usage in a sports context:](http://www.sportsjoe.ie/football/embarrassing-stat-highlights-how-bayern-munich-ran-rings-around-arsenal/47882)

> ### Embarrassing stat highlights how Bayern Munich ran rings around Arsenal

[Definition (from Free Dictionary Idioms, can't find a better source):](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/run+rings+around)

> **Run rings around**. Also, **run circles around**. Be markedly superior to, as in *Ethan runs rings around David in chess*, or *In spelling, Karen runs circles around her classmates*.

As you can see from the examples, you use it in present tense if you're saying X is, as a characteristic, dominant in ability over Y, and in past tense if you're saying that, on a particular occasion, X did dominate Y by outperforming them.

Answer (score 1):

[**Owned**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/owned?s=t)

- to acknowledge as one's own; recognize as having full claim, authority, power, dominion, etc.
- to totally defeat, gain control over, or dominate in a competition

=> *I totally owned the last two levels of the game.*

=> *He owned the season from beginning to end and took the world title.*

See also: [**Pwnd**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pwned?s=t)

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the verb **outpower** in your example which means:

> [with object] To exceed in power; to **defeat by superior power or
>   force**.

Actual usage:

> On a cold and windy evening, Serena Williams easily advanced to the
>   quarterfinals of the Omnium Du Maurier Canadian Open in Montreal,
>   defeating Anna Kournikova in straight sets. Seeded fourth, Williams
>   **outpowered her Russian opponent** whom she had never played before in
>   front of a full stadium of nearly 11000 spectators.

[[HurriyetDailyNews.com article](http://www.hurriyetdailynews.com/serena-williams-ousts-kournikova-in-montreal.aspx?pageID=438&n=serena-williams-ousts-kournikova-in-montreal-2000-08-19)]